# Does CakePHP 1.3 have any concurrency control?

Tags: cakephp, concurrency, cakephp-1.3

Does anybody know if CakePHP 1.3 have any type of concurrency control, that blocks read/write operations in a table if someone is already writing in it? If not, does anybody knows where I can find examples, or where exactly sould I modify to accomplish this?

Comment: are you looking for transactions? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html

Comment: or 1.3 manual.. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1633/Transactions

Comment: If you are using mysql check out InnoDB.

Comment: thanks, but I'm using Firebird

Answer (score 0):

Use InnoDB in conjunction with transactions.

The saveAll() function uses transactions.